# When is it necessary to declare return function type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, static-analysis, typing

If I have the following basic function `typescript` can infer the return type automatically.

```
function myFunction(x: number, y: number) {
  return x * y;
}
```

Is it only useful to declare return types if `typescript` cannot infer the return type because some other call is leaking `any` and so it cannot make a proper inference?

```
function myFunction(x: number, y: number) {
  return x * y || callThatReturnsAny();
}
```

In this case I would want to type it if I know `callThatReturnsAny()` returns a `number`

```
function myFunction(x: number, y: number): number {
  return x * y || callThatReturnsAny();
}
```

Although the best solution would just be to type `callThatReturnsAny()` so that `typescript` can make the inference? But in that case when should you really ever use explicit return types?

Comment: Did you mean to use binary or?

Comment: @JaredSmith yes, thank you.

Comment: It is never *necessary*, you can declare it whenever you like.

Comment: @zerkms just to be more explicit as a style decision? Otherwise, I know it is not necessary - but does is there ever a good use case for doing so?

Comment: If you do it - you ensure that the returned value type is the same as you expected.

Comment: if you use --noImplicitAny compiler option it will give an error each time you use explicit any like in callThatReturnsAny; than you can type function with any type have the safe code and save some typing on the function where the compiler can infer types

Comment: Similar discussion on [GitHub Omitting function return type and --noImplicitAny #2313](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2313)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I switch on `noImplicitAny` and avoid adding type annotations in almost all cases, except functions. Why? Because I don't want to accidentally return a union type when:

1. I forget to return a value
2. I return a value of the wrong type

For example, my day goes differently if I start off with:

```
function example(a: number, b: number) {
```

vs

```
function example(a: number, b: number): number {
```

Here's what happens next...

```
function example(a: number, b: number) {
    if (a > 5) {
        return 5;
    }

    if (b > a) {
        return 'b';
    }
}
```

My return type is now `number | string | undefined`.

If I use the return type annotation, I get additional help*.

It helps you return the correct type:

[image: Wrong return type]

In strict mode, it makes sure you return something every time.

[image: Missing return (strict mode)]

*** if you like additional help, you'll also have *all the strict things switched on*.

Comment: I thought of one use case when it might be useful, the inferred type matches up with a custom type but isn't specifically typed as so. For example, if you return `{ foo: string }` implicitly, which matches up with an interface `interface Foo { foo: string }` then it may be useful to explicitly return type `Foo` in case `Foo` changes.